# What am I supposed to insert in assets generated with controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm playing around with Rails 3.2 and I have noticed that every time I generate a controller, Rails creates a js and css file having the same name in the assets folder.

I'm aware of the introduction of assets pipeline in Rails 3.1 but I'm not sure what code I'm supposed to insert in each of those files.

All the js and css specific for the actions included in the controller? Or how am I supposed to organize my assets?

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you generate a ProjectsController, Rails will also add a new file at app/assets/javascripts/projects.js.coffee and another at app/assets/stylesheets/projects.css.scss. You should put any JavaScript or CSS unique to a controller inside their respective asset files, as these files can then be loaded just for these controllers with lines such as <%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %> or <%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] %>. See [asset_pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is like I was imagining.